# Navigation Properties between Views in EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to define navigation properties between Views in EF with code first? Please, note that I do not need any tool generating any code for me. I would like to know whether or not this can get done and the logic behind this.

Suppose you have a project in which you will only work with views. No data will be created, updated or deleted (at least by you). All you need to do is queries and all you have are views.

Suppose now a second scenario in which you can also have tables, but your purpose is only to visualize data (you will treat them as views). However, there is not always a foreign key referencing the primary key of the parent table in relationships.

**My question is**: Can I define navigation properties in these scenarios? Or do I have to relay on joins only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on this myself. Everything I'm reading indicates you have to manually edit the .edmx files so that the views are considered tables and manually add the nativation properties yourself. Downside is if you resync against the database you have to repeat the process all over again.

Re:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dcbdfe52-6ba7-4e75-94aa-51c88b57635c/adding-navigation-property-to-a-view?forum=adodotnetentityframework